# Converting Date to Name

Tags: r, date

I have date's in a dataframe with corresponding sampling date as presented by the sample dataframe:

```
   Date            Temp
   2016-06-11      5
   2017-08-19      12
   2018-01-21      13
   2019-04-28      7
```

The date column is in numeric format currently. I want to convert the numeric month (i.e. 06) into its full name (i.e. June) but am having trouble with the conversion.

I did check the converting dates to names question but was confused by the select DATENAME.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include tags that will help the right people find your question, such as the programming language and library you're working with. Please also include your best attempt so far based on what you've already read, along with its exact output, including the full text of any error messages.

Comment: What programming-language are we talking about?

Comment: R is the coding language I am using

Comment: `df$Date <- format(as.Date(df$Date,format="%Y-%m-%d"),"%B")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may simply use `months()`. *Example:*

```
d <- transform(d, date.m=months(v))
d
#         date          x   date.m
# 1 2020-10-01 -1.1390886  October
# 2 2020-11-01 -0.6872151 November
# 3 2020-12-01  1.0632769 December
# 4 2021-01-01  1.7351265  January
```

**Note:** If your date is not of class `"date"` you also need to wrap `as.Date`:

```
d <- transform(d, date.m=months(as.Date(v)))
```

---

*Data:*

```
d <- structure(list(date = structure(c(18536, 18567, 18597, 18628), class = "Date"), 
    x = c(-1.13908860117162, -0.687215137639502, 1.06327693201579, 
    1.73512650928455)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```